# how i run query in CDA with ktr?

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, kettle, cda

i want to create chart from ktr file by  CDA in Pentaho bi server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CDADescriptor>
   <DataSources>
     <Connection id="weather" type="kettle.TransFromFile">
  <KtrFile>farzanspoon.ktr</KtrFile>
  <variables datarow-name="PHONE" variable-name="TEMP"/>
</Connection>
   </DataSources>

   <DataAccess access="public"
            cache="true"
            cacheDuration="3600"
            connection="weather"
            id="current"
            type="kettle">
  <Columns/>
  <Parameters>

    <Parameter default="9121901111"
               name="PHONE"
               type="String"/>
    </Parameters>
    <Query>current_conditions</Query>
    <Output indexes="0,1"/>
</DataAccess>


</CDADescriptor>
```

in CDA i send phone number as TEMP(variable defined in ktr) but get this error

*"Error Executing Query"*

[this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxjJ_gZ-RT2EcTV2U2NzWWcyQmc) is my ktr and db

Comment: can you clarify the URL you're using to hit CDA - it should be something like XXXX.cda?PARAMTEMP=123. Can't recall if PARAM needs to be caps or not.

Comment: I think your variable and parameter names must match. Also, you should have a more detailed error in the server logs.